# Which hook will use for checking taxonomy term page

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I need to run a hook on every taxonomy term page load.

```
function mymodule_WhichHook(){
   if (arg(0) == 'taxonomy' && arg(2) == 'term' && is_numeric(arg(2)) ) {
    // Store taxonomy details to DB
   }
}
```

Which Hook can i use for this. Please suggest.

Comment: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.api.php/function/hook_taxonomy_term_load/7

Comment: Not working. Just tried this code.  <?php
function mymodule_taxonomy_term_load($terms) {
echo <pre>; print_r($terms); exit;
}

Comment: Make sure you have cleared your drupal cache.

Comment: @Andrew consider adding your suggestion and well formatted answer.

Comment: This works for me  <?php
function term_taxonomy_term_load($terms) {
$tid = $terms[1]->tid;
$vid = $terms[1]->vid;
db_insert('term_search')
    ->fields(array(
      'tid' => $tid,
   'vid' => $vid,
      'timestamp' => REQUEST_TIME,
    ))
    ->execute();
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may implement  [hook_taxonomy_term_load](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.api.php/function/hook_taxonomy_term_load/7)  in your module